# internet connection failure without restart

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wifi, internet

My problem is that my internet connection works great when I start up my computer, but if I don't use the internet for a while it stops working. It says I still have a connection but anything that uses the internet doesn't work anymore. When I restart my computer it works again, but again if I leave it for a while it quits. I am running Linux Mint 18. Does any one know what to do to fix this. Changing the configuration file so it doesn't have power saving options enabled or restarting the network manager doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like your card (wifi probably) goes to sleep and enables power saving options. Identify your card and search for disabling power saving options for your card.

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service` does what? solves the problem in current session?

Comment: Please explain what is to broad about the question so I can edit it to match criteria.  @GAD3R

Answer (score 0):

Due to a change in Ubuntu's network manager, wifi power management is now enabled by default for most wireless cards.  In order to disable power management open a terminal window and enter

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Reboot